# Rails 4 - how to upload .csv file without an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, paperclip

In rails 4, I am using paperclip gem to file uploads. I am trying to upload a .csv file but it is displaying an validation error like `has contents that are not what they are reported to be`

In model, I am validating a file as below,

```
validates_attachment_presence :document
validates_attachment :document, :content_type=>{:content_type=>'text/csv'}
```

Bundled paperclip gem is,

```
paperclip (4.3.5, 4.2.2)
```

Sometimes it will works fine but most of the time it shows the above error.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Don't you upload CSV imported from excel?

Comment: No. Directly I have created CSV file and uploaded.

Comment: Try to check mime type of a file you created with some tool. For example http://mime.ritey.com

Comment: Yeah I agree with Maxim. Check the mime type with a tool. It may be different I guess.

Comment: I have checked with working .csv file. It returns `The MIME type for your file is: text/csv` Same file will not work for other testing system but it works in my localhost.

Comment: Same file when I tried in testing system(windows) I got `The MIME type for your file is: application/vnd.ms-excel`, so how can I fix the above issue?

Comment: Open that file and try to save that(save as) again with `CSV comma delimited`, since I guess that's the common format that is used across the web.